# URL REQUEST URI - IF URL Contains X do Y else do Z PHP

Tags: php, css, url, if-statement, transition

I'm having issues creating a php if statement to match my needs for navigation selection.
Whenever the user moves from one page to another I would like the CSS of the nav button to change, specifically matching the page the user is currently viewing. This is done by using the URL.

columns = default CSS for nav.
selected = page selected CSS for nav.

I have been working on a piece of code to do the job. Currently it uses the URL to search for a desired string; `$find1 ='index`.

I initialize the code by setting the $selector variable to the default style for the navigation, defaulting it to a page which isn't being viewed. It then gets the URL and searches for the string; this is then used to start the if statement; where the variable $selector is changed into `$selector = 'selected'`

```
<?php $selector = 'columns'; ?>

<?php
$path1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$find1 = 'index';
$pos1 = strpos($path1, $find1);
if ($pos1 !== false): $selector = 'selected'; ?>


<a href="index.php"><div id="<?php echo $selector;?>">Home</div></a><?php endif ?>
```

When the page is loaded, the specific nav button shows the correct CSS. However the other nav buttons are not displayed, hinting toward the fact that the $selector has not been set to anything for that occurrence.

I then tried another way of coding the function;

I added "2" to all the variables to ensure duplication and glitching was not a problem, as well as changing the page name:

```
<?php $selector2 = 'columns'; ?>

<?php
$path2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$find2 = 'about';
$pos2 = strpos($path2, $find2);
if ($pos2 !== false): $selector2 = 'selected'; else: $selector2 = 'columns';?>


<a href="about.php"><div id="<?php echo $selector2;?>">About</div></a><?php endif ?>
```

This time when the "index page" is loaded the nav buttons are both gone.

I am unsure as to where or how I have gone wrong when using this code, but I am sure it is down to my if statement.

If someone would help to re-create or re-jig this code to make it work or to be closer to working, I would appreciate it!

Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the previous answer! I have found  an alternative for this though; Hence why I'm listing it as another answer.

Firstly, go ahead by setting a "page variable" to each page on the site of which is linked to the coloured nav bar. For example; on the index page the variable set will be equal to "index".

```
<!DOCTYPE html
      PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

     <?php $thisPage = 'index' ?>
```

On the nav include, the following script must be added to each href or div tag (however you may have listed them):

```
<a href="index.php"><div <?php if ($thisPage=="index") {
echo " id=\"selected\""; } else { echo " id=\"columns\""; } ?> >Home</div></a>
```

This code takes the name of the variable set on the page and asks weather it is equal to a certain value or string. If there is a match the, "id=\"selected\"" will be echoed within the div tag holding the navigation button.

If it does not contain the required string or value it will instead, (else), echo "id=\"columns\"" into where the navigation button is held.

I have had an intermittent error using this in Chrome, for an unidentified index, strangely, for " "id=\"columns\"" ", to fix this I simply played ball and added the value as a variable.`<?php $none ='id=\"columns\"' ?>`. I know this variable wont be used and it will not cause any further errors. It solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Your `<?php endif ?>` at the end is encompassing your HTML, so whern `if ($pos2 !== false):` is true, your HTML will not show.

```
<?php $selector2 = 'columns'; ?>

<?php
$path2 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$find2 = 'about';
$pos2 = strpos($path2, $find2);
if ($pos2 !== false): $selector2 = 'selected'; else: $selector2 = 'columns'; endif; ?>


<a href="about.php"><div id="<?php echo $selector2;?>">About</div></a>
```